# Помогите пожалуйста распутать ветки в git

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сразу скажу что мне очень важен коммит **Forgot password functional (FPF)** (предпоследний) и вся коричневая ветка (раньше она была master)
В общем, использовал функционал гита впервые и сделал ошибки, пытался исправить, и, как видите, наделал их еще больше:

1. (начинаем снизу) запушил в origin/master ветку, которая не мастер.
2. продолжил работать в локальном master и зачем-то сделал новую ветку
   для FPF. (не помню как это произошло)
3. слил две ветки (одну из них уже удалил).

Получилась вот такая запутанная история.
Мне сложно в этом разобраться. Не знаю с какой команды начать. Если бы Merge меня устроил, я бы оставил и так, но он показывает разницу с FPF. Хотя конфликты решал самостоятельно.

Что в идеале нужно:

- Я бы удалил Merge(никак не могу).
- Светло-зеленую ветку я бы убрал.
- И FPF бы присоединил к коричневой, чтоб в одну линию было.

Если невозможно, то предложите какое-нибудь простое решение. Очень благодарю.

Comment: Кстати, как решение: могу ли я как-то залить master (без ветвлений) на другой репозиторий (и какой командой)? Потом скопировать куда-нибудь проект, остановленный на FPF (без папки .git). Клонировать ту ветку master с репозитория, скопировать сохраненный проект обратно (без .git) и сделать коммит FPF. Так бы я смог решить свою проблему?

Comment: ¿Зачем удалять merge? В нем же как раз изменения Forgot password functional смерджены. ¿Почему не можете удалить, если все-таки приспичело? "никак не могу" не является описанием проблемы. "Светло-зеленую ветку я бы убрал." - это же ветка мастер.

Comment: Очень сумбурно написали. Не понятно ни что за проблемы с текущим сосотянием репозитория, ни какое желаемое состояние. начните с того, что опишите конечную цель, а именно какие ветки должны остаться, какие комиты, из тех что есть в репозитории, должны быть в тех ветках.

Comment: Удалять merge мне нужно, потому что я неправильно смержил. "если бы Merge меня устроил, я бы оставил и так, но он показывает разницу с FPF." Я думал в megre будет FPF, а там чтто-то усредненное.  Я работаю из idea и там недоступна кнопка Undo commit и Revert commit на merge-коммите. Конечная цель - оставить всю коричневую ветку + перенести на нее коммит FPF. Сейчас master действительно зеленая ветка, но раньше она была коричневой

Comment: Если merge неправильный, то забейте на этот коммит. Переведите ветку lostbranch на коммит Forgot password functional (если ветка удалена, то создайте заново), переведите ветку мастер на коммит, на который указывает origin/master, переведите HEAD на lostbranch. Вот и все.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В итоге создал новый репозиторий на гит. Залил туда всю ветку с FPF (да простят меня знающие)

Answer (score 0):

1. перейдите на ветку master `git checkout master`
2. передайте свои коммиты в удаленную ветку `git push origin master`
3. удалите ветку lostbranch `git branch -D lostbranch`

Comment: Вы считаете это сработает? У меня master сейчас указывает на merge коммит (последний). Он мне не нужен. Он неправильно смержился. Мне нужен предпоследний, и он не на master ветке, а lostbranch-ветке.

Comment: сработает конечно, Merge коммит вам ничем не помешает

Comment: а merge коммит туда попадет? И почему вы удаленное решение предлагаете? локально решить нельзя?

Comment: Можете не пушить. Т.к. вы уже слили обе ветки вместе. Вы можете перейти на master и удалить lostbranch